# Android RelativeLayout adding rules before API17

Tags: android, android-layout

I' m writing an Android app with minSdk=14. I have an activity with RelativeLayout, in which are placed some views. when I press the button in this Activity, I must add 5 views in this layout: 2 textviews, 2 editTexts and one ImageView. I'm trying to do this in this way:

```
    CustomTextView fromLabel = new CustomTextView(this);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams paramsForFromLabel = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT); //ширина, длина
    paramsForFromLabel.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, lastCounterId);
    paramsForFromLabel.topMargin = 10; 
    fromLabel.setId(counterIds.get(5*counterMax)); 
    fromLabel.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER); 
    fromLabel.setText(R.string.labelCommunalCounterFrom); 
    int newFromLabelId = fromLabel.getId(); 

    EditText from = new EditText(this);
    from.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams paramsForFrom = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.number_width), ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    paramsForFrom.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, lastCounterId);
    paramsForFrom.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, fromLabel.getId());
    from.setId(counterIds.get(5*counterMax+1));
    int newFromFieldId = from.getId();

    paramsForFromLabel.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_BASELINE, newFromFieldId); 

    CustomTextView toLabel = new CustomTextView(this);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams paramsForToLabel = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT); 
    paramsForFromLabel.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, lastCounterId);
    paramsForToLabel.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, from.getId()); 
    paramsForFromLabel.topMargin = 10; 
    toLabel.setId(counterIds.get(5*counterMax+2)); 
    toLabel.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER); 
    toLabel.setText(R.string.labelCommunalCounterTo); 
    int newToLabelId = toLabel.getId(); 

    EditText to = new EditText(this);
    to.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams paramsForTo = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.number_width), ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    paramsForTo.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, lastCounterId);
    paramsForTo.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, toLabel.getId());
    to.setId(counterIds.get(5*counterMax+3));
    int newToFieldId = to.getId();

    paramsForToLabel.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_BASELINE, newToFieldId); 

    ImageView dropCounter = new ImageView(this);
    dropCounter.setId(counterIds.get(5*counterMax+4));
    dropCounter.setImageResource(R.drawable.cancel_icon);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams paramsForDrop = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    paramsForDrop.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, lastCounterId);
    paramsForDrop.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, to.getId());
    paramsForDrop.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);

    layout.addView(fromLabel, paramsForFromLabel);
    layout.addView(from, paramsForFrom);
    layout.addView(toLabel, paramsForToLabel);
    layout.addView(to, paramsForTo);
    layout.addView(dropCounter, paramsForDrop);
```

The problem is: for second View (`EditText from`), the rule `RIGHT_OF` is ignored. All other fields displayed well.
And the next question is: how can I rewrite rule for the View? I have a button with XML-specified `LAYOUT_BELOW` rule. How can I change it programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed! It sounds stupid, but the problem was:
I've set an id=0 for my first View (first TextField). And when I tried to refer this ID, this rule was ignored. When I set ID=1 - all problems disappeared!
Sorry for this question! I wasn't carefull during docs reading: we can use POSITIVE integers as View ID.